# Testing for 'noise' at the start and end of a segment without regex

Tags: java, regex, string, match

I'm writing code that receives a segment of data as a string. The string will be of varying sizes but always starts and ends with the same characters ( start: `'<s-'` end: `'-e>'` ). I would like to prevent user error in entering invalid characters before the start and the end of the segment. e.g.

```
"fdslkjds<s-hello-e>"
"<s-there-e>dfsad"
"eiend<s-john-e>dfafsd"
```

I know that this can be done by importing the regex library (pattern and matches). But I would like to attempt this without using those libraries. Is there any other way to do it? I've been looking in the String library but can't find the exact method I need.

Comment: Avoiding regex here adds a lot of work. Why do you want to avoid them?

Comment: No, it doesn't add a lot of work, @user270349, look at Ryan Carlsons answer.

Comment: @Ingo You are right. I was thinking about removing the noise, not testing for it. My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As The Guy with The Hat says, there are enough functions for strings such as [startsWith](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) and [endsWith](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29) to achieve your goals.

```
if(!userString.startsWith("<s-") || !userString.endsWith("-e>")) {
  throw new Exception("Please do not enter invalid characters before the start and the end of the segment");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you take a look at [`Strings`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html)'s [`startsWith()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) and [`endsWith()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29) methods.

I would also suggest that you make the code yourself, but if you don't want to bother with that, here is some code that should work:

```
String input = [your code here]
while(!input.startsWith("<s-") || !input.endsWith("-e>"))
{
    System.out.println("Error! Invalid input! Please try again:");
    input = [your code here]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) and [`lastIndexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29) to find the positions of `<s-` and `-e>` in the string and use [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) to extract the proper substring without any "noise".

```
String s = "eiend<s-john-e>dfafsd";
String s2 = s.substring(s.indexOf("<s-"), s.lastIndexOf("-e>") + 3);
```